# Publishing to Rabbitmq, Channel is closed error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, amazon-s3, rabbitmq

I am trying to publish to RabbitMq. At first it runs smoothly, but on second try an error pops up that the Channel is closed but I am opening and closing channel every time. It was working fine when I was encoding(base64) the media file and then publishing the message, but when I decided that instead of encoding I save the file on remote machine and upload it directly by publishing the message with the file path.

This is what I am doing.

```
def get_connection_channel(self):
    if self.channel is None:
        self.logger.info("Creating MQ connection channel on local host")
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.logger.info("Channel created")
    return self.channel

def close_connection_channel(self):
    self.channel.close()
    self.connection.close()
```

I am a beginner, trying to sharpen my skills.

Comment: We'll need a bit more code to help. What does the script to call these functions look like?